# Trigger to update duration between two dates

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project of a car rental at the moment. I want to create a trigger that will calculate the number of days between two dates, and display it in a new column. So I realized I need to alter my `bookings` table because I don't have a `duration` table.

```
ALTER TABLE bookings
ADD duration varchar(10);
```

After altering, I think I need to create an update trigger because `DATEDIFF` function is used for querying. Could someone help me with this trigger? E.g. Count the amount of days between 10th March and 15th March - 5 days. Any help is appreciated. I assume it will be an `UPDATE` trigger??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would require both an insert and an update trigger for this purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE bookings(booking_start_date date, booking_end_date date, duration int unsigned);

CREATE TRIGGER insert_bookings BEFORE INSERT ON bookings 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.duration = DATEDIFF(NEW.booking_end_date, NEW.booking_start_date);

CREATE TRIGGER update_bookings BEFORE update ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.duration = DATEDIFF(NEW.booking_end_date, NEW.booking_start_date);

INSERT INTO bookings(booking_start_date, booking_end_date) values("2019-03-25","2019-03-27");

UPDATE bookings set booking_start_date = "2019-03-24" where booking_start_date = "2019-03-25";

SELECT * FROM bookings;
```

However, if you are using MySQL 8.0+, you can make use of generated columns by defining your column `duration` as `DATEDIFF(booking_end_date, booking_start_date)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help first of all. I'm not exactly sure how this trigger works. So... I have the table, You create 2 triggers Insert/update.. and then - Does the INSERT INTO go under the bookings table with rest of records? Why do you use dates in the update statement - is that when someone is querying it, right? So it's like an example query for each of the triggers? Thanks for the explanation with 8.0 SQL